# the difference between minecraft PE and vanilla minecraft is

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am still unsure what the difference between minecraft PE, and what vanilla minecraft is.

Comment: This question can also be opinion based because not everyone agrees on what to consider "Vanilla".

Comment: Are you asking one question or two? Do want want to know what vanilla MC is, or are you referring to the PC version?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between vanilla Minecraft and the Pocket Edition is:

Vanilla Minecraft is Minecraft without mods or plugins.  No changes to the game itself are made.  What you are given and can get without using means outside of what has already been programmed. Minecraft with command block changes is also considered vanilla

The Pocket Edition for Minecraft is for devices other than the PC.  Phones, Tablets, Touchpads, really any mobile devices.  The exception to this rule is Windows 10.  Windows 10 is able to function with the Pocket edition.

Vanilla just refers to an unchanged-unmodded Minecraft.  Even though PC and PE has many differences in game play I believe that both would be considered Vanilla, because as long as they remain unchanged they are both Minecraft.

Here is a video that describes what `Vanilla` really means.  [Vanilla Minecraft](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIJJYHDVNpc)